# drools dependencies for developing web app with embedded drools rules engine

Tags: drools

I've developed a stand-alone drools application, with rules implemented via .drl files. I'm used the Eclipse IDE to develop the app. I want to embed this application in a web application using the tomcat web server package. I'd like to create a web app project in Eclipse and add the drools dependencies to the project, as needed. Which drools libraries/artifacts do I need to add to the project, e.g. kie and drools libraries/artifacts?

More specifically, if I create a maven-based web-app project using Eclipse. What other maven artifacts will I need to add to the POM for the drools capabilities?

The logic in the web application servlet will create a kie container and session, instantiate a set of Facts based on model definitions, insert the Facts into the session, fire the rules, and respond to the initial http request based on the results of rules evaluation.

Comment: Is your Eclipse project already a maven project?

Comment: @EstebanAliverti Sorry for the delayed response. I have created both web app and drools projects using Eclipse. I don't usually create Maven projects in Eclipse but I can do so if needed. I'm assuming that I would create a maven web app project and then add drools dependencies to the project. Thanks for your interest in my question.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the question I posed above a while ago. I'm posting an answer to close the question. I came up with a set of maven dependencies that I used to create a java servlet application that initializes and invokes an embedded DROOLS rules engine to process an http request. I've successfully tested the servlet-based application within a Tomcat server (v8.5). I used the Eclipse IDE to create the application as a maven-based project. The pom.xml file for the application has the following dependencies.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.1</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.4</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.kie</groupId>
  <artifactId>kie-api</artifactId>
  <version>6.5.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
  <artifactId>drools-core</artifactId>
  <version>6.5.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
  <artifactId>drools-compiler</artifactId>
  <version>6.5.0.Final</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
  <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
  <version>2.8.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.json</groupId>
  <artifactId>json</artifactId>
  <version>20180813</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```